# Allow only iframes from certain websites

Tags: php

Does anyone know of a way in php to take a block of text and remove iframes if they aren't from a domain in a whitelist array or black list array? So i can allow iframes from like YouTube, Facebook, but not every website.

Comment: Not sure what you need this for, but be aware that this may not be a 100% effective solution. Take, for instance, this link - http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&h=f9234 - Looks like Facebook, doesn't it? But it is actually to the Facebook Redirector which then sends you to Google. The same code could be modified to send people anywhere, but any test of this URL will say that it is a Facebook URL (until the redirection, of course).

Comment: @Lucanos You are absolutely correct. Though you could add that to a *blacklist*, but it could become a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @Keverw Why the bounty? Can you please add a comment and tell me why my answer didn't work, and I will modify it to suit.

Comment: Your code worked. I wanted to see what other people thought. Yours didn't really have code comments so hard to learn from. Maybe you could update it? Like i was not sure what Strip www was for.

Comment: @Keverw OK, I shall add some comments, check the answer now :)

Comment: @Keverw If you need any more help, don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: Would it be possible to edit $iframe->parentNode->removeChild($iframe); to replace the iframe? I'm going to remove it in my real app, but i have another use that would be similar code to upgrade YouTubes Flash embed codes to the Html5 iframe ones. I'm kinda on that Anti-Flash Trend.

Comment: @Keverw Yes it would. Except, you would place your new element after it, and then remove the `iframe`. I'll code up a quick example and update my post with it.

Comment: It's vital you remove the Iframe and re-create it - As a malicious user I could quite easily add an onload attribute (and set the src on the fly.) which would get past most third party XSS filters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Input

```
<h3>Allowed</h3>
<iframe src="http://youtube.com" ></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com" ></iframe>
<iframe src="http://google.com" ></iframe>

<h3>Banned</h3>
<iframe src="http://example.com" ></iframe>
<iframe src="http://alexanderdickson.com" ></iframe>
```

#### PHP

```
// Make a list of allows hosts.
$allowedHosts = array(
  'youtube.com',
  'facebook.com',
  'google.com'
);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);

// Get all iframes in the document.
$iframes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
$iframesLength = $iframes->length;

// Iterate over all iframes.
while ($iframesLength--) {
     $iframe = $iframes->item($iframesLength);
     if ($iframe->hasAttribute('src')) {

         // Get the src attribute of the iframe.
         $src = $iframe->getAttribute('src');

         // Get the host of this iframe, to compare with our allowed hosts.
         $host = parse_url($src, PHP_URL_HOST);

         // If not host, then skip this iframe.
         if ($host === NULL) {
             continue;
         }

         // Strip www. because otherwise it may be 'www.facebook.com` and we have only
         // banned `facebook.com`.
         $host = preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $host);


         // If this host is not in our allowed list, remove it from the document.
         if ( ! in_array($host, $allowedHosts)) {
             $iframe->parentNode->removeChild($iframe);
         }
     }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/HPFJBOEu).

#### Output

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> 
<html><body> 
<h3>Allowed</h3> 
<iframe src="http://youtube.com"></iframe> 
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com"></iframe> 
<iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe> 

<h3>Banned</h3> 

</body></html>
```

If you didn't want the returned HTML wrapped in all `html`, `body`, etc, then run this code at the end...

```
$html = '';
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $node) {
   $html .= $dom->saveXML($node, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
}
```

If you have >= PHP 5.3.6, replace [`saveXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) above with [`saveHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php).

#### Update

> Would it be possible to edit `$iframe->parentNode->removeChild($iframe);` to replace the `iframe`?

Yes, replace that whole block with...

```
// Create video element
$video = $dom->createElement('video');

// Attach whatever you need to...
$video->setAttribute('src', 'whatever');

// Get a reference to the parent of the iframe
$parent = $iframe->parentNode;

// Insert the video element before the iframe
$parent->insertBefore($video, $iframe);

// Remove the iframe
$parent->removeChild($iframe);
```

Comment: Cool. I updated the code pad http://codepad.org/25AqXKDz with the code that removed the HTML wrapped in all html, body. It adds "&#13;". It works in Chorme but kinda annoying. Great so far. Not sure it its the $dom->saveXML($node, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG); or what.

Comment: @Keverw I've never seen that before. Looks like it is encoding the new line. What version of PHP do you have?

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.7 i tested it on and it did the same thing as the CodePad i put in my last comment.

Comment: @Keverw OK, the `saveHTML()` accepting a node as an argument is meant to be supported >= PHP 5.3.6, but try it :)

Comment: "DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters"  $html .= $dom->saveHTML($node, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG); Thats the code. So i guess not? I tried  $html .= $dom->saveHTML($node); also... Not in a hurry, maybe i should wait till the repo in Ubuntu gets updated. I can work on other parts of the project till then. Hope its not long.

Comment: @Keverw Yeah, I thought that would be the case. Is there anything else I can can help you with ?

Comment: Nope. Thanks for all the help! Marked it accepted answer. Says i have to wait 22 hours for the bounty to give that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a HTML DOM Parser such as PhPQuery, and just iterate through all the iframe tags, and remove any that has src that doesn't start with youtube, and the other sites in your whitelist. Then just print the resulting HTML.